# UDN2981 - Discharge issues

Tags: led, current-source

I want to drive a LED seven-segment display multiplexed.
For the high-side switch I have a UDN2981(TD62783APG).
It's running on about 80Hz @ 5V.
When I hook it up to a scope I can see that when its Input goes low,
the output has a capacitor-like discharge curve of about 1ms starting
from that point.

Why does it do that?
How can I remove it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no pull-down resistor inside the darlington output stage hence, if you just connect your o-scope as load, the output voltage will drop quite slowly: -

[image]

Try connecting a 1 kohm resistor as load and see what happens.

Comment: This does the trick. Do you know any alternatives for the UDN? Maybe something especially for LED displays without external pull-down.

Comment: Ah but you don't need an external pull-down - as soon as the transistor turns off, any residual charge in the wire to the LED is "consumed" by the impedance of the LED and, although it might look like there is still a slow discharge curve, that is only because the LEDs are no longer taking current hence, the circuit does not need a push-pull driver to work. Just try it and see.

Comment: Now I'm confused... If I probe in-circuit I get a discharge-curve. If I add a pulldown resistor it disappears. Same thing open-circuit. Why does it do that?

Comment: Because a LED doesn't conduct all the way down to 0 volts - at about 2 volts it stops conducting abruptly and you are left with a slow discharge curve after that.